# Is it possible to hide header actions in tree-grid?

Tags: lightning-web-components

It seems that as of this writing, specifying `hideDefaultActions: true` in column definitions for `lightning-tree-grid` does not work. I am trying to find some workaround. It seems that, while hacky, CSS may be a path forward. However a selector for `lightning-primitive-header-actions`, or any variation thereof, does not seem to be applied to the relevant DOM elements.

**HTML**

```
<lwc-tree-grid ...attributes>
<lwc-tree-grid>
```

**CSS**

```
lightning-primitive-header-actions { display: none; }
```

For now I am just trying to even hide *all* actions. I have not gotten to the point where I try to hide only the default actions on columns that have both. If CSS will work at all, I should be able to figure out the relevant selectors.

Am I barking up the wrong tree here? Can CSS be used as a workaround? Would it require me to extend the tree grid component somehow?

The only alternative I can think of is to extend `lightning-datatable` and completely rebuild a custom `tree-grid` which actually respects the attributes I want. The only other column attribute I care about which is currently not respected is `fixedWidth`, but I can live with resizeable columns. That approach seems like a much larger effort.

Is there any way to hide the default actions on a tree grid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Shadow DOM](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.create_dom) prevents you from using anything other than [Styling Hooks](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/platforms/lightning/styling-hooks/). You would necessarily need to write your own component. Fortunately, you can borrow the code directly from [lightning-base-components](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lightning-base-components) or use the [tree](https://github.com/salesforce/base-components-recipes/tree/master/force-app/main/default) from [salesforce/base-components-recipes](https://github.com/salesforce/base-components-recipes).

Comment: Except I don't want `tree`, I want `tree-grid`, for which they do not share the recipe. Are you saying `Styling Hooks` do not work unless I write a component which extends `tree-grid`?

Comment: @AdrianLarson I guess I got ahead of myself for that part. Still, lightning-base-components should be a path forward. CSS can't target components inside a child component, as the Shadow DOM bit explains. As far as I know, lightning-tree-grid isn't extensible, only lightning-datatable is. I had a link to cross-compiled lightning components in the c namespace, but I can't find it right now.

Comment: I assumed as much with the child DOM. Ugh, sounds like a major headache.